# React Native App crashes on Network error

Tags: android, react-native

I am developing one document upload app, using react native. 
Documents get uploaded if the network is good, but suddenly the app crashes if the network goes down.
For instance - If I am uploading the documents on 4G network then i receive success from API but if the network speed suddenly goes down to 2G network i.e. 20KB/S then I get "NETWORK REQUEST FAILED / NETWORK ERROR" and the app crashes.

I have handled the error using catch block, but still the app crashes, what should I do to avoid this crashing even if the network is not available or if the speed goes down ?

Below is my code -

```
try{
var form = FormData();
form.append("user_id",this.state.userId);
form.append('file', {
        uri: this.state.path,
        type: 'image/jpg',
        name: 'image.jpg',
});
axios({
method:"POST",
url:"http://xxxxx/xxxx",
timeout:50000,
data:form
})
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(error=>console.log(error));

}
catch(error){
console.log(error);
ToastAndroid.show("Internal error, please try again");
}
```

Note - I have used react-native-image-picker, as the document can be captured using camera OR it could be uploaded from the existing file present in the device.

Also have added all permissions in Manifest file for internet access.

Please help

Comment: Did you find any solution or root cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

Thats an Exception. I guess you need to catch the Exception 
BadNetwork or Timeout You need to Catch it and App should not Crash just make sure 
In the Catch You need to Show the Dialog box which says Can't connect to server.
OR You need to check if you have a Network connection then only Let the user send the Request show Non-cancelable Dialogbox 
Hope that helps .

Comment: I've already added try catch block and axios also has an catch block, but I am not able to get even the console.log(), and how can i prevent crashing ? i.e. app should not crash and stay as it is with an error message in toast ? 
Please help