# when using fetch, axios, etc.`catch` doesn't handle the error, instead your app crashes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

To make sure that our request will be successful, first, we check the internet connection then send our request.
like this:

```
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(async isConnected=> {
  if(isConnected){
    try {
       let result = await fetch(MY_REMOTE_SERVER);
       console.log("result: ", result)
    } catch (error) {
       console.error("error: ", error);
    }
  }
  else ToastAndroid.show('No internet', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
});
```

Everything was fine, until I faced this issue: consider a situation in which access to a server for some countries is blocked.

So, although the internet connection is ok, each time I was getting `network request failed` error.
I couldn't find the problem because expected the `catch` to print the error, but my app was just crashing.

Now that I know the reason, I don't know how to solve it.
For example, when the connection can't be made I want to alert the user to use a VPN or leave the app because they are in an embargoed country!

On the other hand, what is the point of catch!? if it doesn't catch the error!
thanks.

Comment: that's probably a bug in react-native if it crashes the APP (in my opinion)

Comment: @JaromandaX I haven't tried it in production mode, but as I'm developing my app, it just keeps crashing with a big red error!

Comment: sounds like a bug in react native if a catch doesn't catch an error - have you searched for such an error in ract native? I mean, there's this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53456551/react-native-app-crashes-on-network-error with no useful answer - and a bug report https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3810 - opened for 6 months now - looks like react-native simply can't handle such a simple error condition

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, you right I've searched a lot but didn't find any solution for this problem. so asked on StackOverflow maybe someone knows a workaround.

Comment: Looking through the source, I couldn't find anything specific that stands out in the implementation, if you can step through the problem with a debugger, you can fix the issue in native for both yourself and others. See [the related source here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/8d5ac8de766b9e435cbfa9bfa6b8a2b75b0e2a19/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/netinfo/NetInfoModule.java#L106).

Comment: @3limin4t0r - I think you fail to understand the nature of the problem - how can an app check for anything if it has **crashed**?

Comment: @Nit thanks for your suggestion, I'll do my best.

Comment: @BlueTurtle Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @RohitKashyap yes, I left an answer for this question, check it out

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a mistake on our side, react-native will crash as it encounters `console.error`.
so by changing the above code to this version you will get rid of the red screen:

```
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(async isConnected=> {
   if(isConnected){
      try {
        let result = await fetch(MY_REMOTE_SERVER);
        console.log("result: ", result)
      } catch (error) {
        // use "log" instead of "error"
        console.log("error: ", error);
        // or you may want to show a toast on error like
        oastAndroid.show('No internet', ToastAndroid.SHORT)
      }
   }else ToastAndroid.show('No internet', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
});
```