# React app 'crashes' due to fetch/axios inability to correctly pass error to catch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch, use-effect

I have a small React app that fetches some resources with `axios` through `UseEffect()` hook. The app itself works fine in debug. However, when I try to test out the build version of my app, it 'crashes', that is, it doesn't render anything aside from setting body background color.

When in debug mode, the app shows 0 errors or warnings, and the only leads the build has is `TypeError`'s for built-in type-specific methods like `.map()`, `.filter()` and `.toLowerCase()` all which, conveniently, are present in components that fetch data with `axios`. After some testing I came to conclusion that the cause of the 'crash' was `axios` (and `fetch()`) that, for a reason unknown to me, doesn't pass the error upon unsuccessful fetch to the `.catch()` block and tries instead to execute `.then()` with undefined `data`, which, in turn, don't have methods like `.map()` or `.toLowerCase()`, cause `TypeError`'s and 'crash' the whole app.

I tried to rewrite all `axios` containing components with `fetch()`, but the result is the same. The closest thing I have found on my own was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464417/when-using-fetch-axios-etc-catch-doesnt-handle-the-error-instead-your-app) for React Native (and not plain React) that advises to change `console.error()` (which crashes the app) to `console.log()`, but it's hardly applicable in my case since I don't use `console.error()` at all.

Below you can find a sample component that fetches data with `axios`:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Salute = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState('john doe');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('/api/user?id=1')
      .then(({ data: { fullName } }) => setUser(fullName.toLowerCase()))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='salute'>
      <h1>
        hi, it's <span id='username'>{user}</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Salute;
```

Comment: you could remove the destructoring and check if data is undefined in the then block

Comment: How is the API responding to errors? Does it still return a `200` http status code with some error payload? If yes, you might need to handle that in the `then` block instead.
If your API returns a `4xx` code, then axios will automatically pass this down to the catch block with the response object inside the `error`.

Comment: @Syder As I said, the app crashes when `axios/fetch()` fail to fetch the data, and therefore data passed to the `.then()` block is undefined which leads to crashing, but it should (I think?) in this case be handled by the `.catch()` block, which it doesn't

Comment: @BrunoPaulino Thanks, I tried to figure out what http status I'm getting, and it turns out I receive `200` instead of `4xx`, and that is the reason why the `.then()` block get's executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of my problem turned out to be faulty API which sends error message with a `200` status code, which in turn was interpreted by `axios/fetch()` as a normal response.

The key takeaway here (at least for me) is to implement at least some minimal data validation in fetching logic so as to prevent the cases like these. In my case, I did the following (until the API I use gets fixed):

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Salute = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState('john doe');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('/api/user?id=1')
      .then(({ data }) => {

        if (typeof data.fullName === 'string') {
          setUser(data.fullName.toLowerCase());
        } else {
          console.log('[AXIOS GET] Wrong data type: ' + typeof data.fullName);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log('[AXIOS GET]', err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='salute'>
      <h1>
        hi, it's <span id='username'>{user}</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Salute;
```